# In what situation we apply log function to geodist function to calculate the distance

Tags: sas

I have two codes and want to know when and why do we apply them

```
1. Geodist(lat1,long1,lat2,long2,'DM');

2.log(geodist(lat1,long1,lat2,long2,'DM')+1);
```

I want to know when and why do we use the second code to calculate distance instead of first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geodist() provides a geographical distance. The second function applies a transformation to the distance. It can be used similar to other area's, when you have data that has a large range and you don't want the larger values to drown out the smaller values. Or if the distribution of the data needs to be normalized for analysis.

Comment: Thank you for answering.